# GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA doesn't do anything

Tags: postgresql

For whatever reason, our database is not respecting GRANT commands. Below is an example with a newly created user.

```
pddbtest=> create user test_user login;
CREATE ROLE
```

then verify user does not have schema permission yet

```
pddbtest=> SELECT rolname, has_schema_privilege(rolname, 'public', 'usage') from pg_roles where rolname='test_user';
  rolname  | has_schema_privilege
-----------+----------------------
 test_user | f
(1 row)
```

then grant permission

```
pddbtest=> grant usage on schema public to test_user;
GRANT
```

then read if permission exists now (it does not)

```
pddbtest=> SELECT rolname, has_schema_privilege(rolname, 'public', 'usage') from pg_roles where rolname='test_user';
  rolname  | has_schema_privilege
-----------+----------------------
 test_user | f
(1 row)
```

Even after granting permission on the schema, which doesn't return any errors, the database still sees the permission as not granted. (if I add a select grant on all tables in schema after, I also still get a schema permission denied error when trying to query any of the tables)

(Search path is "$user",public should that information be relevant)

EDIT: Here is the output of SELECT version(); and \dn+ as requested:

```
PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit


                             List of schemas
   Name    |     Owner      |         Access privileges        | Description 
-----------+----------------+----------------------------------+------------------------
 fnrbaks   | appuser_root   |                                  |
 mask      | maint_user_2   | maint_user_2=UC/maint_user_2+    |
           |                | readonly_viewer=U/maint_user_2   | 
 pganalyze | appuser_root   | appuser_root=UC/appuser_root    +| 
           |                | pganalyze=U/appuser_root        +| 
           |                | pganalyze2=U/appuser_root        | 
 public    | rdsadmin       | appuser_root=UC/rdsadmin        +| standard public schema
           |                | proddb=U/rdsadmin                | 
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce this in a quick test. Can you add the result of `select version();` and `\dn+` in psql please?

Comment: @DanielVérité thank you for taking a look at this! I've updated my post with the requested output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `public` schema belongs here to `rdsadmin`. A possible explanation to the GRANT not working is that it's run by an under-priviledged user (not `rdsadmin` and not superuser) that doesn't have the right to grant rights on `public`:

```
grant usage on schema public to test_user;
```

By default if that grant is ineffective, a warning is displayed:

```
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"
```

but it depends on the `client_min_messages` setting. If that setting is below the warning threshold (for instance it's set to `error`), then the warning is not displayed and you'd have the behavior shown in the question. This can be verified with:

```
 SHOW client_min_messages;
```

and changed to a more verbose level with:

```
SET client_min_messages TO notice;
```

Comment: ah, yes this was it! the message level was suppressing the WARNING, and apparently rdsadmin didn't give the root user the GRANT OPTION to assign USAGE permissions to other users. thank you thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and contacted AWS support;

Template0 owner is rdsadmin. You should not use it to create a new database.
Template1 owner is root (Master user). You should usee it to create a new database.
[...]we are not able to alter the schema owner back to rdsadmin, as it is a super user reserved for RDS. So, you should never use the template0 to create a database.

In my case it could be fixed by running:

```
alter schema public owner to root;
```

Comment: relatedly, this was also a good solution for the case where a masteruser creates a database and then alters owner but ... changing the ownership of the database didn't change the ownership of the public schema